# C#, extract double from USARTs receive char buffer

Tags: c, embedded

my USART is receiving a string from a "black box" and the string contains two doubles and few hex values. The string is placed in my buffer rbuf.buf with a total size of 32 characters. Normally I receive 19 characters but few times extra erroneous characters at the end. The buffer typically looks like this (in hex):

0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x2e, 0x34, 0x35, 0x20, 0x36, 0x37, 0x2e, 0x38, 0x39, 0x20, 0x37, 0x41, 0x41, 0x20, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00, ...

I want to extract the two doubles 123.45 and 67.89 and have among several other examples tried following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

...

```
void buffer_to_float(void)
{
static char string1[10] = "";
char *string2;
for(uint8_t i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
  char c = rbuf.buf[i];  // this is a char but how do I make it a pointer?
  string2 = strcat ( string1, c );  // ... "char" is incompatible with "char*" ...
  }

double R = atof(string2);
printf("%lf\n", R);
}
```

I know I'm doing something silly here but what?
I use an interrupt routine for receiving the string, should I do the extraction there or should this routine be as short/quick as possible?

Thanks for telling me how silly I am, I think I need it ;-)

Comment: You really, really should not do any of the formatting/conversion/floating point "stuff" in an interrupt function.  You are right to keep that part as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sscanf` function to read your two `float` values:

```
char bla[] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x2e,
              0x34, 0x35, 0x20, 0x36,
              0x37, 0x2e, 0x38, 0x39,
              0x20, 0x37, 0x41, 0x41,
              0x20, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x00};

float a, b;

sscanf(bla, "%f %f", &a, &b);
printf("%f %f\n", a, b);
```

Comment: Thank's ouah!  <br\>Problem solved!  <br\>I changed to   <br\>    sscanf(rbuf.buf[], "%f %f", &a, &b); ...

Comment: However, instead of 123.45 I now get 123.449999 so I need to round the float.

Comment: What is the problem with this?  In your processor's floating point version of the world 123.45 _IS_ 123.449999.  The value 123.45 probably cannot exist.

Comment: Hi Ian, no problem. Just that I did not think long enough. One correction for others: I changed the second last line to be   sscanf(rbuf.buf, "%f %f", &a, &b);  then it worked also with my USART. Thanks again for good help!